# What signals shouldn't be blocked by thread in multi-threaded program in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, signals

I have a multi-threaded program. I want to handle all meaningful signals in a single thread. That's what I do before creating any thread:

```
sigset_t signal_set, old_set;

sigfillset(&signal_set);
// What signals should I leave unblocked here?
pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &signal_set, &old_set);

std::thread( /* some args */ );

pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &old_set, nullptr);
```

But my good sense suggests leaving some signals unblocked, since there is a plenty of situation when signals may be sent directly to specific thread: `SIGSEGV` or `SIGPROF` - I believe, it's as good as leaving unblocked `SIGINT` in an interactive program.

---

Are my suggestions correct about those two signals (`SIGSEGV`, `SIGPROF`)?

What other signals should I leave unblocked following some common sense?

Comment: Wouldn't that common sense tell the same thing for per process signaling?

Answer (score 3):

Asynchronous signals (that's most of them, including anything sent by the `kill` command/function and signals generated by the controlling terminal like `SIGINT`) are deliverable to any thread in the process that has the signal unblocked, so there's no need to keep them unblocked in all threads. If you're using a dedicated signal handling thread, you want them blocked in all threads except the signal handling thread.

Synchronous signals on the other hand are delivered to a particular thread as a result of an action by that thread. They include `SIGPIPE`, `SIGBUS`, `SIGSEGV`, `SIGFPE`, etc. Except for `SIGPIPE`, none of these should happen at all unless you have serious bugs in your program, and you probably want to block `SIGPIPE` anyway so you can instead get the `EPIPE` error and handle this condition properly. So for the most part I would say it doesn't hurt to just block them all. If you really find yourself *needing* to handle `SIGSEGV` or such, you probably should rethink the reasons, but in the mean time feel free to unblock it.

Comment: Congratulations on reaching 100k!

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even notice til your comment.